# What is the adjective for a child who has finished kindergarten education?

Tags: word-choice

Preschool seems to be the word typically used for children's education before they enter elementary school. But how do we call a child who has finished preschool education? Is it valid to use *preschooled*? I just Googled for this term and found no such usage.

Comment: One tends to call them *preschool* children until the point at which they become *school* children.

Comment: Maybe *sixish*?

Comment: "A graduate of the finger-painting academy"?

Comment: @Oldbag: And possibly *cum laude*.

Answer (score 5):

In Britain we would say that they were a ***child of normal school age***, (or ***of school age***).

This would mean either that they had reached their fifth birthday (from when education becomes compulsory), or that they were a *rising five* and, depending on the local schools' admissions criteria, were eligible for a school place.

Perhaps because there is no legal requirement for a child to be pre-schooled, though nowadays almost all children are, there would seem no requirement for a word which means 'pre-schooled'.

A pre-school institution is usually, nowadays, called ***a day nursery***. The word *kindergarten*, resonant of the private-school sector, is a bit old fashioned, nowadays.

Comment: +1 for *school age*. But in the US, the usual age for entering kindergarten is around 5 years old. Six year olds attend what we call *first grade*. Also, may US jurisdictions do not require schooling until age six.

Answer (score 2):

In the USA, kindergarten is not part of pre-school, but part of [regular education](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_education_in_the_United_States). So, a kid either done with preschool or never gone to preschool is [kindergarten ready](http://www.babycenter.com/0_kindergarten-readiness-is-your-child-ready-for-school_67232.bc). Kindergarten is part of elementary or primary school in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

*Kindergarten graduate* (sounds sweet!)

[Picture on Chicago Tribune](http://www.chicagotribune.com/chi-martrell9diploma20090609111125-photo.html)

[jotform](https://www.jotform.com/form-templates/kindergarten-graduate) has a form for registering a "Kindergarten graduate"

> Use this form insert details of the child graduating from kindergarten.

[Oscar Grady Public Library](http://www.oscargradylibrary.org/?p=5633) has a program called

> 1,000 BOOKS BEFORE KINDERGARTEN GRADUATE!

Comment: The programme is called “1,000 Books before Kindergarten”. The page you link to shows a girl who is a graduate of the _programme_. She has not graduated kindergarten—if she had, she wouldn’t be eligible for the programme at all!

Comment: And in first grade we can refer to our distinguished pupil as being enrolled in *post-kindergarten graduate studies*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The purpose was to show the use case.

Comment: @Drew "post-kindergarten studies" -- see usage.